# Git workflow to test feature branch

Tags: git, branch, workflow, release

I am looking for some guidance on how developers can test their own feature branch in a new Test environment. We have set up a new TEST server / TEST Database and we would like our developers to test their feature branches in this environment. This is how we envision the workflow.

1. Developers will create their feature branch from *master* branch.
2. Once they are ready to test their feature, they will merge into *develop* branch (no peer reviews) and build and deploy to TEST server from this develop branch.
3. Once they are happy with their testing, they will create a PR from their feature branch to merge into *master*, after peer reviews.

Is this approach feasible ? We have 5 to 6 devs in our team. Currently each developer deploy directly from their feature branch to this TEST server and that causes the changes by developer overwritten by the others. So we thought of adding this *develop* branch to avoid the issue mentioned above. One issue I can see with this approach is if both Dev A and Dev B wants to test their changes and if Dev B's changes causes the app in Test server to crash. Then Dev A has to wait for his testing until Dev B fixes the Test environment. Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow is fine. Some suggestions:

1. Obviously you can call your branch names whatever you'd like, however, I would recommend calling your test branch something other than `develop`, only because that name is a standard branch name used in [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), where it is intended to be the starting point for new development, and will always be merged into `master`, eventually. People familiar with Git Flow might think `develop` means something other than the way you intend to use it. I would suggest you instead call it `next`, which is what the maintainers of Git call the test branch you describe, in [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows).
2. Reset your `next` branch periodically from `master` so that all the test code that doesn't make the cut gets purged. Depending on how long it takes to validate the code you can shorten or lengthen your reset frequency. At my company we currently reset `next` every Sunday.
3. When developer's branch off of `master` for new work, if `master` is ahead of the last time `next` was reset, when those branches merge into `next` they will bring in all the new commits from `master` along with the new commits to be tested. Depending on how the merges are done, this may cause confusion (for example in the context of PRs into `next`). If you are using PRs for that merge and the additional commits are muddying the change list, consider having them merge in the latest `master` first, followed by a merge of their own branch so they can isolate their own changes in a separate merge.

**Tip:** When one developer breaks the build of the `next` branch, if they cannot immediately fix it, the easiest thing to do is simply revert the merge commit of their branch, which effectively undoes their merge.

Comment: could you please explain the scenario for line 3 ? "if master is ahead of the last time next was reset, when those branches merge into next they will bring in all the new commits from master along with the new commits to be tested". We will never merge from "next" to master.We were planning to always merge from the feature branch to master, after test completes successfully. May be I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @user636525 Sure! Suppose `next` is reset to `master` on Monday, and they are both on commit `A`. On Tuesday, `master` has 3 more commits (B,C,D). You create a feature branch off of `master` and add commit `E`. Now you go to test your branch by merging into `next`, and you are the first person to test in `next` since it was reset (so `next` is still on commit `A`). Your merge into `next` will bring in 4 commits (B,C,D & your commit E). If you are using a tool such as GitHub, etc, your PR will show 4 commits and more files than you edited in just commit `E`.

Comment: @user636525 cont... Seeing those extra commits is expected, but if you find it annoying, you could first merge `master` into `next` (to bring in just B,C,D) and then do another PR with your feature branch into `next` to isolate `E` in a single PR.